# Please convert this code from python javascript

Tags: javascript, python

```py
def sumOdd(n):
if n <= 0:
    return -1
else:
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum = sum+2*i-1
    return sum
```

Please convert this code to javascript since what I was trying before was not working as expected. This function is supposed to print the sum of the first N odd numbers more than 0. This is what I was doing before but it wasn't working:

```js
function sumOdd(n) {
  if (n<=0){
    return -1;
}
  else {
    var sum = 0;
    for (let i=1; i<=n; i++){
        console.log(i);
        sum = sum + 2 * i - 1;
    return sum;
    }
}
```

Please give me the correct translation.

Comment: Just take the `return` out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Check your indentations and braces in the JavaScript :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. The `return` needs to be outside the loop.

```js
function sumOdd(n) {
  if (n<=0){
    return -1;
  }

  var sum = 0;
  for (let i=1; i<=n; i++) {
      sum = sum + 2 * i - 1;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

I've also removed the `else` because due to the `return` this has the same effect and I think this is more readable (fewer nesting levels with a very idiomatic return-on-invalid-input at the top).